# Can this enumeration problem be generalized? (counting $20$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots 30\}$ with no three consecutive elements)

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I found a problem in a brazilian contest that goes as follows:

In how many ways can we select $20$ elements among $\{1,2,3,\dots, 30\}$ such that no three consecutive elements are chosen?

My solution:

> Split the elements into groups of $3: \{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\dots \{28,29,30\}$ and notice that we must pick two from each group. There are three options for each group, and we call the group a "left", "center" or "right" group depending on the "missing" element. Notice that a "left" group cannot appear to the left of a "center" or "right" group, and a right group cannot appear to the right of a "center" or "left" group. Hence, selecting the quantity of each kind of group uniquely determines the arrangements, so the answer is the number of solutions to $l+c+r=30$ in non-negative integers, which is $\binom{32}{2}$ by stars and bars.

This solution clearly used that $\frac{20}{30}=\frac{2}{3}$. Is it possible to solve it for $k$-subsets of $[n]$ such that no three elements are consecutive? (I am especially interested in whether the answer can be computed efficiently, it's probably possible to do this with a $2$-dimensional recurrence but that doesn't seem very efficient)

Comment: You are not considering {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7},  etc.

Comment: what ? ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we have a row of $n$ squares, and we have to shade in $k$ of them, without shading three in a row.

Any pattern of that description can be constructed out of tiles looking like this:

$$\blacksquare\blacksquare\square\qquad\blacksquare\square\qquad\square$$

(The tiles cannot be rotated or flipped. The last square is always $\square$, so it can be ignored.)

Assume that we have $p$ of the first kind of tile, and $k-2p$ of the second kind, and any number of the third kind. Then the problem is equivalent to lining up those tiles in a row of length $n+1$.

As there are three kinds of tiles, we know by elementary counting that the number of arrangements will be of the form $\binom{a+b+c}{a,\ b,\ c}=\frac{(a+b+c)!}{a!\ b!\ c!}$.

The total number of tiles used must be equal to the number of squares, minus the number of tiles of the second kind, minus twice the number of tiles of the first kind:

$$(n+1)-(k-2p)-2(p)=n-k+1$$

Thus the number of arrangements for specific $p$ is the trinomial:

$$\binom{n-k+1}{p,\ k-2p,\ n-2k+p+1}$$

And we have to sum that over all relevant $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n$ is the number of  elements and $k$ the size of the subset.
The idea  here is to construct  a generating function  by choosing the
first element of each subset and thereafter appending a series of gaps
between adjacent values, marking  runs of consecutive elements. We use
$w$ for these runs and $u$  to mark runs of at least three consecutive
elements and $z$  for ordinary gaps of size at least  two. We also use
$v$ to count elements. We then have from first principles the OGF

$$f(z,w,u,v) = \frac{vz}{1-z}\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{v^q z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q}
\\ \times \left(\sum_{p\ge 0} (vw+uv^2w^2+uv^3w^3+uv^4w^4+\cdots)^p
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{v^q z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q}\right)^p\right)
\\ \times (1+vw+uv^2w^2+uv^3w^3+uv^4w^4+\cdots) + 1.$$

As a sanity check we should get all subsets from

$$\frac{1}{1-z} f(z,z,1,1)$$

(the multiplier  by $1/(1-z)$ sums the contributions  as these subsets
are classifified according to the last element). We obtain

$$\frac{z}{1-z} \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q}
\\ \times \left(\sum_{p\ge 0} (w+w^2+w^3+w^4+\cdots)^p
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q}\right)^p\right)
\\ \times (1+w+w^2+w^3+w^4+\cdots) + 1.$$

This simplifies to

$$\frac{z}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-z^2/(1-z)}
\left(\sum_{p\ge 0} \frac{w^p}{(1-w)^p}
\left(\frac{z^2/(1-z)}{1-z^2/(1-z)}\right)^p\right)
\frac{1}{1-w} + 1
\\ = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}
\frac{1}{1-wz^2/(1-z)/(1-w)/(1-z^2/(1-z))}
\frac{1}{1-w} + 1
\\ = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}
\frac{1}{1-wz^2/(1-w)/(1-z-z^2)}
\frac{1}{1-w} + 1
\\ = z
\frac{1}{1-z-z^2-wz^2/(1-w)}
\frac{1}{1-w} + 1
= z \frac{1}{(1-z-z^2)(1-w)-wz^2} + 1.$$

To conclude we put $w=z$ and get

$$z \frac{1}{(1-z-z^2)(1-z)-z^3} + 1
= z \frac{1}{1-z-z^2-z+z^2+z^3-z^3} + 1
\\ = z \frac{1}{1-2z} + 1 = \frac{1-z}{1-2z}.$$

We see that on multiplying by $1/(1-z)$ we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\frac{1}{1-2z}.}$$

There are $2^n$ subsets and the sanity check goes through.

Now to eliminate subsets containing three consecutive elements we
compute

$$\frac{1}{1-z} f(z,z,0,v)$$

which yields

$$\frac{vz}{1-z}\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{v^q z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q}
\\ \times \left(\sum_{p\ge 0} v^p w^p
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{v^q z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q}\right)^p\right)
\\ \times (1+vw) + 1$$

which is

$$\frac{vz}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-vz^2/(1-z)}
\times \left(\sum_{p\ge 0} v^p w^p
\left(\frac{vz^2/(1-z)}{1-vz^2/(1-z)}\right)^p\right)
\times (1+vw) + 1
\\ = \frac{vz}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-vz^2/(1-z)}
\times \left(
\frac{1}{1-v^2wz^2/(1-z)/(1-vz^2/(1-z))}\right)
\\ \times (1+vw) + 1
\\ = \frac{vz(1+vw)}{(1-z)(1-vz^2/(1-z)) - v^2wz^2} + 1
\\ = \frac{vz(1+vw)}{1-z-vz^2 - v^2wz^2} + 1.$$

On replacing $w$ by $z$ and multiplying by $1/(1-z)$we thus have

$$\frac{1}{1-z}\frac{vz+v^2z^2}{1-z-vz^2 - v^2z^3} + \frac{1}{1-z}.$$

The second  term only contributes for  $k=0$ while the  first does not
contribute when $k=0.$ This means there is one subset of zero elements
not containing  three consecutive elements, namely the  empty set, and
this is obviously true.

Simplifying we find

$$\frac{1}{1-z}\frac{vz+v^2z^2-(1-z)/z}{1-z-vz^2 - v^2z^3} 
+ \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-z-vz^2 - v^2z^3} 
+ \frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = \left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)\frac{1}{1-z}
+ \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-z-vz^2 - v^2z^3} 
\\ = -\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{1-z-vz^2 - v^2z^3}
\\ = -\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-vz^2/(1-z) - v^2z^3/(1-z)}.$$

Observe that

$$[v^k] \frac{1}{1-vz^2/(1-z) - v^2z^3/(1-z)}
= \sum_{q=0}^k [v^k] \frac{v^q z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q} (1+vz)^q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k \frac{z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q} [v^{k-q}] (1+vz)^q
= \sum_{q=0}^k {q\choose k-q} \frac{z^{2q}}{(1-z)^q} z^{k-q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k {q\choose k-q} \frac{z^{k+q}}{(1-z)^q}.$$

The coefficient extraction in $z$ now proceeds as follows:

$$[z^n] \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-z} 
\sum_{q=0}^k {q\choose k-q} \frac{z^{k+q}}{(1-z)^q}
= [z^{n+1}] \sum_{q=0}^k {q\choose k-q} 
\frac{z^{k+q}}{(1-z)^{q+1}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^k {q\choose k-q} 
[z^{n+1-k-q}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{q+1}}.$$

We have the closed form which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{q=0}^k {q\choose k-q} {n+1-k\choose q}.}$$

Listing these values in a triangular format we find

$$1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 4, 6, 2, 0, 1, 5, 10, 7, 1, 
\\ 0, 1, 6, 15, 16, 6, 0, 0, 1, 7, 21, 30, 19, 3, 0, 0, 1, 
\\ 8, 28, 50, 45, 16, 1, 0, 0, \ldots$$

which points us  to [OEIS A078802](https://oeis.org/A078802) where the
above analysis is confirmed.

The above computation was supported by the following Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local list, pos, res;

    if k < 3 then return binomial(n,k) fi;

    res := 0;

    for list in choose(n, k) do
        for pos to k-2 do
            if list[pos] + 1 = list[pos + 1] and
            list[pos + 1] + 1 = list[pos+2] then
                break;
            fi;
        od;

        if pos = k-1 then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;

X1 := (n, k) ->
coeftayl(coeftayl(-1/z+1/z*1/(1-z-v*z^2-v^2*z^3),
                  v=0, k), z=0, n);

X2 := (n, k) ->
add(binomial(q,k-q)*binomial(n+1-k,q), q=0..k);
```

In particular for  subsets of twenty elements of  a set containing the
integer range from  one to thirty the number  of subsets without three
consecutive elements is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{66.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $m$ be a fixed positive integer.  We say that a subset $S$ of $U:=\{1,2,\ldots,3m\}$ is *eligible* if $|S|=2m$ and $S$ does not contain $3$ consecutive elements of $U$.  Let $A_k:=\{3k-2,3k-1,3k\}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,m$.  We note that each eligible subset $S$ of $U$ must omit exactly one element from each $A_k$.  We say that $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,m+1\}$ is *bad* with respect to $S$ if $3k-2\notin S$.  (Obviously, $m+1$ is always bad for any eligible subset $S$)

Observe that, if $k$ is bad with respect to $S$, then any $j\in\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots,m+1\}$ is also bad with respect to $S$.  For $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,m+1\}$, write $N_k$ for the number of eligible subsets $S$ such that $k$ is the smallest bad integer with respect to $S$.  It can be easily seen that
$$N_k=k$$
because, for some $t\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,k-1\}$, $S$ must omit integers of the form $3r$ for $r\in\{1,2,\ldots,t\}$ and omit integers of the form $3r-1$ for $r\in \{t+1,t+2,\ldots,k-1\}$.   Thus, the total number of eligible subsets $S$ is
$$F(m):=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\,N_k=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\,k=\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2}\,.$$
In particular,
$$F(10)=\frac{11\cdot 12}{2}=66\,.$$